# calling into external contracts keeping the same msg.sender

Tags: solidity

Consider following two simple contracts.

```
contract Provider {
  uint public constant value = 42;                                                                                                               
  event Caller(address addr);                                                                                                                    

  function provide() external returns (uint) {                                                                                                   
    emit Caller(msg.sender);                                                                                                                     
    return value;
  } 
}
```

```
contract Counter {
  uint public counter;
  address public provider;
    
  constructor(address addr) {
    counter = 0;
    provider = addr;
  }

  function newvalue() public {
    counter += Provider(provider).provide();
  }
}
```

Let's say `Provider` is deployed at `0x1` and `Counter` is deployed at `0x2`.
Now a user with address `0x3` calls `newvalue`.

The event emitted from `provide` contains `0x2` as `msg.sender`. (i.e. the address of `Counter`)

Is there any way in which the original sender (i.e. `0x3`) can be seen as msg.sender in all internal transactions?

Note that this is not an ideal curiosity. Many protocols have hardcoded transfering of tokens to `msg.sender` instead of taking an additional `to` argument. This makes calling those functions form other smart contracts extremely unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one can use `DelegateCall` as explained here:

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#simple-smart-contract